# Setting a property from button click wix

Tags: wix

Can anyone tell me if it possible to be able to set a property when a user clicks a button in my Wix installer. I am using Wix 3.6. I know you can set directories but I have tried properties using this but it gives the error that the value must be a directory ID:

```
  <Publish Dialog="KeyDlg" Control="Demo" Property="[VARIANT]" Value="Demo" Order="1">1</Publish>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `Property` attribute of the [`<Publish/>`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_publish.htm) element.

Comment: I already have, it says: `Set this attribute's value to a property name to set that property` which i have done. Is it wrong?

Comment: The property should be without square brackets `[]` - just the property name